# Add Soap Envelope with XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

This is my source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SSC>
    <ErrorContext>
        <CompatibilityMode>1</CompatibilityMode>
        <ErrorOutput>1</ErrorOutput>
        <ErrorThreshold>1</ErrorThreshold>
    </ErrorContext>
    <User>
        <Name>LIF</Name>
    </User>
    <SunSystemsContext>
        <BusinessUnit>SHA</BusinessUnit>
    </SunSystemsContext>
    <MethodContext>
        <Transaction>
            <TransactionType>IFA</TransactionType>
        </Transaction>
    </MethodContext>
    <Payload>
            <SalesInvoice>
            <AcknowledgementAddress>4113611600</AcknowledgementAddress>
            <CompletionDate>28112022</CompletionDate>
            <CustomerCode>4113611600</CustomerCode>
            <EntryDate>28112022</EntryDate>
            <InvoiceAddressCode>4113611600</InvoiceAddressCode>
            <InvoicePeriod>0112022</InvoicePeriod>
            <MiscellaneousDescription1>Ministry of Public Order</MiscellaneousDescription1>
            <SalesDefinitionCode>IFA</SalesDefinitionCode>
            <SalesInvoiceId>13</SalesInvoiceId>
            <Status>3</Status>
            <TransactionDate>28112022</TransactionDate>
            <Line>
                <CreditStatus>0</CreditStatus>
                <CurrencyCode>LEK</CurrencyCode>
                <DeliveryAddressCode>4113611600</DeliveryAddressCode>
                <DemandQuantity>100.00000</DemandQuantity>
                <DispatchStatus>99</DispatchStatus>
                <UserLineNumber>1</UserLineNumber>
            </Line>
        </SalesInvoice>
    </Payload>
</SSC>
```

I need to transform it to this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <InvoiceTransmission>
            <InvoiceTransmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd" />
            <InvoiceTransmissionHeader>
                <InvoiceCreationDate>2022-12-16</InvoiceCreationDate>
                <Version>2.0.2</Version>
            </InvoiceTransmissionHeader>
            <Invoice>
                <InvoiceHeader>
                    <CustomerEntityID>3611600</CustomerEntityID>
                    <IssuingEntityID>-</IssuingEntityID>
                    <IssuingEntityName>Air BP Albania</IssuingEntityName>
                    <InvoiceNumber />
                </InvoiceHeader>
                <InvoiceSummary>
                    <InvoiceLineCount />
                    <TotalInvoiceLineAmount>0</TotalInvoiceLineAmount>
                    <TotalInvoiceTaxAmount>000.00</TotalInvoiceTaxAmount>
                </InvoiceSummary>
            </Invoice>
            <InvoiceTransmissionSummary>
                <InvoiceMessageCount>1</InvoiceMessageCount>
            </InvoiceTransmissionSummary>
        </InvoiceTransmission>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi soapenv" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <InvoiceTransmission> 
                    <xsl:element name="InvoiceTransmission"> 
                        <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />           
                        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="SSC"/>
                </InvoiceTransmission>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="User | SunSystemsContext | MethodContext | ErrorContext"/>

    <xsl:template match="Payload">
        <InvoiceTransmissionHeader>
            <InvoiceCreationDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')" />
            </InvoiceCreationDate>
            <Version>2.0.2</Version>
        </InvoiceTransmissionHeader>

        <xsl:for-each select ="SalesInvoice">
            <Invoice>
                <InvoiceHeader>
                    <CustomerEntityID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(CustomerCode, 4)" />            
                    </CustomerEntityID>  
                    <IssuingEntityID>-</IssuingEntityID>
                    <IssuingEntityName>Air BP Albania</IssuingEntityName>
                    <InvoiceNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(Line/SalesInvoiceTransactionReference)" />    
                    </InvoiceNumber>
                </InvoiceHeader>
                <InvoiceSummary>
                    <InvoiceLineCount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max(Line/SalesInvoiceLineNumber)" />
                    </InvoiceLineCount>
                    <TotalInvoiceLineAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(Line/VLAB18/Trans/VSilVlabEntry_Val)" />
                    </TotalInvoiceLineAmount>
                    <TotalInvoiceTaxAmount>000.00</TotalInvoiceTaxAmount>
                </InvoiceSummary>
            </Invoice>              
        </xsl:for-each>
        <InvoiceTransmissionSummary>
            <InvoiceMessageCount>1</InvoiceMessageCount>
        </InvoiceTransmissionSummary>                   
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Everything works fine except soapenv:Envelope element. It's copies attributes to each element, and I need them only in this one. So my final XML now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <InvoiceTransmission xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <InvoiceTransmission xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd" />
            <InvoiceTransmissionHeader xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <InvoiceCreationDate xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">2022-12-16</InvoiceCreationDate>
                <Version xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">2.0.2</Version>
            </InvoiceTransmissionHeader>
            <Invoice xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <InvoiceHeader xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <CustomerEntityID xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">3611600</CustomerEntityID>
                    <IssuingEntityID xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">-</IssuingEntityID>
                    <IssuingEntityName xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">Air BP Albania</IssuingEntityName>
                    <InvoiceNumber xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
                </InvoiceHeader>
                <InvoiceSummary xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <InvoiceLineCount xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
                    <TotalInvoiceLineAmount xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">0</TotalInvoiceLineAmount>
                    <TotalInvoiceTaxAmount xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">000.00</TotalInvoiceTaxAmount>
                </InvoiceSummary>
            </Invoice>
            <InvoiceTransmissionSummary xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <InvoiceMessageCount xmlns:doc="urn:bp:xi:dwn:rm:pf:merchant:sales:100"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">1</InvoiceMessageCount>
            </InvoiceTransmissionSummary>
        </InvoiceTransmission>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please what should I change to get my desired result?
For transformation I have .NET program written using Saxon 10.8.

.NET main function:

```
using System;
using Saxon.Api;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using java.nio.file;

namespace TestingXsl
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = "";
            string req = "";
            string file = "pokus_so.xml";
            string fileSAP = "out.xml";
           
            XsltTransformator trans = new XsltTransformator("transform_so.xsl");

            data=File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8); //where file is input XML path
            req=trans.TransformString(data);

            File.WriteAllText(fileSAP, req, Encoding.UTF8); //where fileSAP is output XML path
        }
    }
}
```

.NET XsltTransformator class

```
using Saxon.Api;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestingXsl
{
    public class XsltTransformator
    {
        XsltTransformer saxon;

        public XsltTransformator(string xsltTemplate)
        {
            Processor saxProc = new Processor();
            XsltCompiler saxComp = saxProc.NewXsltCompiler();

            XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(xsltTemplate);
            XsltExecutable saxExec = saxComp.Compile(xr);

            saxon = saxExec.Load();
        }

        public void TransformFile(string inFile, string outFile)
        {
            Stream sr = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open);
            saxon.SetInputStream(sr, new Uri("http://testing.com"));

            XmlWriter xmw = XmlWriter.Create(outFile);
            TextWriterDestination twd = new TextWriterDestination(xmw);

            saxon.Run(twd);
            twd.close();
            xmw.Close();
        }

        public string TransformString(string inData)
        {
            Stream sr = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sr);
            sw.Write(inData);
            sw.Flush();
            sr.Position = 0;

            saxon.SetInputStream(sr, new Uri("http://testing.com"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            XmlWriter xmw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws);
            //XmlWriter xmw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding=Encoding.UTF8});            
            TextWriterDestination twd = new TextWriterDestination(xmw);

            saxon.Run(twd);
            twd.close();
            xmw.Close();

            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + sb.ToString();

            return xml;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you run Saxon 10.8 from the command line with your input and XSLT, do you then get that alleged output with all the duplicated namespace declarations? If not, can you show us the relevant .NET code you use to run the transformation and serialize the result, so that we can reproduce the result?

Comment: Sorry, now I updated my post with .NET code snippet

Comment: Can you please also check whether Saxon 10.8 NET from the command line also give that unwanted result? Or post a complete, executable code snippet we can use to reproduce the result you have.

Comment: Also, which Saxon API is that, the official one s9api from the official Saxonica 10.8 HE product release? I am not sure where stuff like `TextWriterDestination` or `SetInputStream` are defined.

Comment: Yes is Saxon 10.8 HE. Updated .NET snippet with using lines

Comment: the `using` declarations alone do not allow me to see which objects you use exactly, either post a minimal but complete sample that can be easily run to be used to reproduce the result you get or preferably first check with the Saxon 10 command line tool whether it produces the same output as your own .NET code.

Comment: So I hope now it should be better. I update my post with complete testing C# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Saxon 10 for .NET

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5565

Sorry about it. We are planning to produce another maintenance release which will fix this, but the task hasn't made it to the top of our list.